# Imaginary component in capacitive reactance

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, complex-numbers

This is a trivial question in first year but, unfortunately, this popped up in an elementary yet compulsory lab experiment.

The capacitive reactance is defined as $$X_{c}=\frac{1}{\omega c}$$
The text I relied on in my first year stated this as the definition.

However, I've came across sources defining the capacitive reactance as
$$X_{c}=\frac{1}{i \omega c}$$

I'm pretty sure both definition are valid and perhaps the latter being more general than the former definition. Could someone be kind enough to fill me in on a little bit more?

Comment: It all depends on whether or not you wish to use complex numbers.  Using complex numbers can simplify calculation greatly but they are not essential to the solution of a problem.  Is this a duplicate?  http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/80582/ and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/109736/

Answer (score 2):

To this EE's eyes, both formulas are incorrect; the reactance of a capacitor is

$$X_C = -\frac{1}{\omega C} $$

and so the sign is incorrect in the first formula.  Since reactance is the imaginary part of impedance

$$Z = R + iX$$

reactance is a *real* number and so the second formula can't be correct.  It is instead the formula for the *impedance* of a capacitor

The *impedance* of a capacitor is

$$Z_C = 0 + iX_C = -i\frac{1}{\omega C} = \frac{1}{i\omega C}$$